# Abdomen vs. stomach vs. belly

Tags: word-usage, usage

As far as I understand all of the three following words are synonyms: 
**Abdomen**, **stomach** and  **belly**, but some of them used in specific contexts. I would like to have a lesson about the usage of them in the UK or US.

For example when pointing on **belly / abdomen / stomach**, and saying that it is nice or flat or muscle. Which word is in the context?

Now I know that stomach in anatomy terminology means a specific organ but when people say that they feel "stomach ache" it means that they mean to the all area of the lower torso, and doesn't refer to the anatomy terminology.

Comment: Have you looked up any dictionaries or made any research? if so, can you share what you have found?

Answer (score 5):

All three words can refer to the part of the body between the chest and the pelvis. Which is used depends on the context and the level of formality desired.

The word "abdomen" is used in medicine to refer to this part of the body. It is also used in discusions of the training of the abdominal muscles.

In medicine the word "stomach" refers to the pouch where food goes when it is swallowed. But it has a second sense of abdomen. For example, one might say, "I want to have a flat stomach".

The word "belly" can also refer to the stomach or the abdomen. However, it carries connotations of fullness. One can "fill one's belly". Children are "the fruit of the belly". If the abdomen is not quite flat one "has a bit of a belly".

For a time the word "belly" was considered vulgar. The word was sometimes slyly hinted at. For example in the 1933 film "42nd Street" Ginger Rogers sings "with a shotgun in his b...tummy". (Tummy is a childish word for belly.) Nowadays this supposed vulgarity of "belly" is completely forgotten, and the joke has to be explained.

Answer (score 0):

From Wikipedia - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abdomen:

> The abdomen (less formally called the belly, stomach, tummy or
>   midriff) constitutes the part of the body between the thorax (chest)
>   and pelvis, in humans and in other vertebrates.

The stomach is part of the abdomen (aka the belly).
[image: Abdomen]

Comment: When people say that they have feel "stomach ache" it means that they mean in the all area of lower torso. This is what I saw. I don't think that people who said that they have "stomach ache" studied anatomy. Isn't it? Even your own source supports what I said ("The abdomen, less formally called the belly, stomach")

Comment: "Less formally" does not mean it is correct. People use words incorrectly all the time and yes you are correct, many people have no clue of the anatomy of the abdominal anatomy. Stomach ache is used often to describe pain the abdominal region, whether it is the stomach, the intestines or somewhere else in that region.